# Why does my angular js service gets destroyed after server call?

Tags: angularjs

As per my understanding services in angularjs are "Singleton". Following is my Scenario where I am using angularjs with Asp.net MVC application.

I have created angularjs service and I use it in one of my controller, which is used on one of the HTML view. If I navigate from that page to some other page, Which results in call to Server then in that case my angularjs Service gets reset. Later, When I come back to the same page my service again gets created/initialized. Can someone please explain me the reason?

Comment: because you are navigating from one page to another page..angular components will be exists when you are not reloading page. this could work if you make your application as a SPA

Comment: What are you trying achieve exactly ?

Comment: Pankaj:  My application is not single SPA rather I am having many different Silo SPA's in my MVC application.

Comment: Luke: I am trying to find justification why my angularjs service gets reset after page navigation which results in call to server.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you use ngRoute or angular-ui routing for making single page app, when you change pages controller gets reloaded, which forces all the logic in controller to run again hence call your service, If you are on the view which use other controller its expected not to run service from first one. Some code would be nice too.
hope this helps.